# Mule ESB (Groovy Script): How would I check a value and add a new key value mapping to a java.util.LinkedList

Tags: java, groovy, mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I am calling a service that returns data from a DB in the form of a LinkedList.  I need to update the LinkedList with a new field called "status" which is determined off of endDate.

- endDate > current date => status=deactivated
- endDate <= current date => status=active

**Mule Payload Class:** java.util.LinkedList

**Mule Payload:** [{serialNumber=, maintenanceId=12345, customerID=09890, startDate=2017-10-10 23:34:17, endDate=2018-10-10 23:34:17},{serialNumber=, maintenanceId=09091, customerID=74743, startDate=2014-8-16 23:34:17, endDate=2019-8-16 23:34:17}]

The issue I am having in mule is that I am unable to navigate into the linked list to retrieve the value as well as add a new value to the list.  Hoping someone could give me some advice on the best way to move forward.  I am trying to use a groovy transformer to update the payload, but it's not going so well, so I don't have any code to show.

Thanks taking the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement (the payload was a JSON but it should work as well) and this is what I did using Dataweave (I added your data so it can be easier to understand).

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
flowVars.input2 map {
    serialNumber : $.serialNumber,
    maintenanceId: $.maintenanceId,
    customerID: $.customerID,
    startDate: $.startDate,
    endDate: $.endDate,
    status: "deactivated" when $.endDate as :date {format:"yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss"} > (now  as :date {format:"yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss"}) otherwise "activated"
}
```

With this transformation you iterate the list and add the status value based on your requirement.

Input example:

```
 [{"serialNumber":"test1", "maintenanceId":"12345", "customerID":"09890", "startDate":"2017-10-10 23:34:17", "endDate":"2018-10-10 23:34:17"},{"serialNumber":"test2", "maintenanceId":"09091", "customerID":"74743", "startDate":"2014-8-15 23:34:17", "endDate":"2018-8-15 23:34:17"}]
```

Output example

```
[{"serialNumber":"test1","maintenanceId":"12345","customerID":"09890","startDate":"2017-10-10 23:34:17","endDate":"2018-10-10 23:34:17","status":"deactivated"},{"serialNumber":"test2","maintenanceId":"09091","customerID":"74743","startDate":"2014-8-15 23:34:17","endDate":"2018-8-15 23:34:17","status":"activated"}]
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Question: I'm not as familiar with DataWeave.  Are you performing the iteration or is that something I'll have to do.  Then would I change flowVars.input2 to payload?

Comment: The payload might be of size 1 or 10, so I won't know how many times it will need to iterate through the payload.

Comment: The map operator iterates the list. The $ operator holds the item value in each iteration. See my edited answer

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go.  One other question, is the INPUT value you are using the same as the PAYLOAD value I'm using?  The information i'm showing is what is getting printed out by a logger message.  I put "Payload #[payload.class] | #[payload]" in my logger message.  I think that is the part that is confusing me the most.  Is it a Linked List of an object or Linked List of a JSON?

Comment: In DataWeave, can you perform AND/OR operator on when statements? For example, serialNumber: $.serialNumber when ($.serialNumber != null OR $.serialNumber != '') otherwise "N/A"

Comment: My input value is a flow var i defined, but you could use as well the payload. You can transform your payload to a JSON using the default transformer. And for the AND/OR question, yes you can. {
  currency: "USD"
} when payload.country == "USA" and payload.currency == "local"
otherwise
{
      currency: "EUR"
}

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked.  I was able to update my payload.